# Excel - Count TIme Cells

Tags: excel, datetime, time, count, countif

I want to count number of cells containing the value time. Eg: 05:29, 14:36, 22:05.

Here, these times are entered in indiviudal cells. And I want to count number of cells containing time. Like Time: 3. But not the time function or total time function

-Thanks

Comment: how is your data organized? Are the time containing cells scattered, or are they all in one column/row?

Comment: Every thing in one row, some cells contain strings in the middle. '05:26 14:36 P 22:05'. But I want to count only the number of time displayed in the row.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting it. Can you show an example of your data?

Comment: Ok. Here it is.                                                                                                                             'A3=05:26, A4=14:36, A5=P, A6=22:05, A7=**"no of time"**, **A8=3**'  @L.Dutch

Comment: You have A8=3   Is A8 to be considered as time?

Comment: Yes, A8=3 is no of time count in 3 cells. its not a time. just a value 3.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is arranged like this
[image]
you can use `=COUNTIF(B1:L1,">0")` to count the non empty cells, and you will get then this
[image]

If you want to check for late arrivals, use this formula `= IF(Q2<>"",IF(Q2-Z2 >0,"L","N"),"")` where I called Q2 the cell containing the arrival time and Z2 the cell with the expected arrival time. You will get a `L` for late arrivals, a `N` for an arrival on time.

Comment: Here I've attached an image. Fill the cells with the header instructions. it looks complicated.   [![Temp_calc.jpg](https://s22.postimg.org/rck58v6v5/Temp_calc.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/aosn6dc3h/)

Comment: According to the image,  "P" means present. If time "9:27", then it is late by the start time. like this will have for a month. each row is an employee record. **F2** should be no of present/p values if user came before or actual start time. **G2** denotes the Letter "L", like P for present. if entry time is 9.00 and user arrives by 15 min late, i need to count the number of 15 min late in **H2**.

Comment: Are Q, R and other the clock in time?

Comment: Yes, they are the entry of start time for each day for every month. there the value will be **P** for _present_, **L** for _absent_, If time entered means, that is late from the starting time. Starting time can be 9:00 AM. and rest is the calculation.

Comment: check the edit to my answer. I think you can start from there.

Comment: Thanks L.Dutch. That works, But actually I made Like this '= IF(D7<>"",IF(D7-Q7>=0,"P",TEXT(Q7-D7,"H:mm")),"")' , that is , if the user is late, then remaining time should be displayed. Start time:**09:00** and user arrives at **09:25**, then it shows **00:25** min.                                          After this, how I've to add this for all days and to calculate the no of days **Present/"P"** and no of mins delayed on each day.

Comment: Here, I'll add this.  I'll enter P, L or the time delay as 09:18 am, then it has to calculate the no of P, no of L and the time delays upto 00:15 min, 00:30 min and 1 hour from starting time.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution along the same lines as L.Dutch is to use the `IsNumber()` function of excel. It requires two steps. First using that function and then summing the `TRUE` values. The one advantage of this method is that it makes it more explicit as to what it will add up.

Thought I'd provide this in case it is useful, but I would use L. Dutch's answer first.